# Tcl code for compare duplicate names with their values

Tags: tcl

i have one file which has 3m of data and the format is given below. i want compare lines inthe file (each lines have there own data). if the same line found compare with its data and store it in output file (small value data), and if unique line found write to output file.
file : **sample_data.tcl**

```
i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_0__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_60__11_  
 **0.777900(5.709091%)**     0.799630(3.05152%)  0.021730(2.633939%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_0__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_58__11_  
 **0.97870(6.076364%)**  0.79990(3.033939%)  0.021800(2.64424%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_1__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_1__44_   
 **0.778180(5.675152%)**     0.798220(3.246061%)     0.020040(2.429091%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_0__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_58__11_  
 **0.77870(5.676364%)**  0.79990(3.033939%)  0.021800(2.64424%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_1/i_tx_top/i_csr/i_reg/txdatgen_seed_udp_reg3_io3_nt_q_reg_20_    
 **0.777320(5.779394%)**     0.803050(2.660606%)     0.025730(3.118788%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_1__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_1__22_   
** 0.777720(5.730909%)**     0.797750(3.303030%)     0.020030(2.427879%)
```

if match found compare with highlighted data

expected output

```
i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_0__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_60__11_  
 **0.777900(5.709091%)**     0.799630(3.05152%)  0.021730(2.633939%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_1__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_1__44_   
 **0.778180(5.675152%)**     0.798220(3.246061%)     0.020040(2.429091%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_0__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_58__11_  
 **0.77870(5.676364%)**  0.79990(3.033939%)  0.021800(2.64424%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_1/i_tx_top/i_csr/i_reg/txdatgen_seed_udp_reg3_io3_nt_q_reg_20_    
 **0.777320(5.779394%)**     0.803050(2.660606%)     0.025730(3.118788%)

i_top/i_module_wrapper_top_0/i_module_dbe_top_0/i_ctrl_top/u_mcu_system/u_ibex_top/gen_rams_gen_rams_inner_1__gen_noscramble_rams_data_bank/gen_generic_u_impl_generic/mem_reg_1__22_   
** 0.777720(5.730909%)**     0.797750(3.303030%)     0.020030(2.427879%)
```

the code what i wrote to get expected output but i am getting wrong data
i just confuted with this logic now

```
set inputFile [open $input_def r]
set outputFile [open $output_filename w+]

set lineNumber 0
set skipLines 0
while {[gets $inputFile line] >= 0} {
    incr lineNumber

    if {($lineNumber % 3) == 1} {
        # Extract the first word until the first tab or space
        set firstWord [string trimleft [string range $line 0 [expr {[string first "\t" $line] - 1}]]]
        # Compare with output file data
        set outputData [gets $outputFile]
        if {[string match "*$firstWord*" $outputData]} {
            # Match found, skip current line and the next two lines
            set skipLines 3
            continue
        }
    }

    if {$skipLines > 0} {
        # Skip current line
        set skipLines [expr $skipLines - 1]
        continue
    }

    # Write the line to the output file
    puts $outputFile $line
}

close $inputFile
close $outputFile
```

can anyone give solution for this

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
# read the data into lines
set inputFile [open $input_def r]
set lines [split [read $inputFile] \n]
close $inputFile

# each group of 3 lines is an "item"
# store the items in a dictionary, keyed by the first of the three lines
set uniq {}
foreach {a b c} $lines {
    dict set uniq $a [join [list $a $b $c] \n]
}

set outputFile [open $output_filename w+]
dict for {key value} $uniq {
    puts $outputFile $value
}
close $outputFile
```